# Load checked items into another page

Tags: javascript, php

I loaded some articles from the database into a page and I want to load only the checked ones using a checkbox into the next page so I can use to create a newsletter. I tried with a normal JS script but I got stuck not knowing what to do next and how to properly recognize the ones I marked.
`

```
<?php
   try{
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TestDb;charset=utf8', 'root', 'TestingDb123');
   }
   catch (Exception $e){
           die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
   }

   $result = $bdd->query('Select Title, Link, Image_Path, pubDate, Description from RSS ');
   ?>

<html>
   <head>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <title>Affichage</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="recherche">
   <input type = "text" name="recherche" class ="rech">
      </div></br></br>
   <div class="btnrech">
   <input type = "button" name="rechercher" value="Rechercher" class="rech">
   </div>
   <?php
      while ($donnees = $result->fetch())
   {
   ?>
      <div class="general">
         <div class="block">
            <div class="line">
               <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="test" value="" id="Selected">
               <h3 class="titre"><?php echo $donnees['Title'];?></h3>
               <p  class="pubDate"><?php echo $donnees['pubDate'];?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="line2">
               <div class="image-article"><img src="<?php echo $donnees['Image_Path'];?>" width="100%" height=""></div>
               <p class="Description"><?php echo $donnees['Description'];?></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </br>
      <?php
         }
         ?>
      <div class="Bouton">
         <input type="button" name="confirmer" value="Suivant >>" class="btn">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: So please share the JS code what you've made. Basically you can just add the "ID" field in your query and echo it in the checkbox value. Than you have edit the name of your checkbox from `test` to `test[]` to treat is as array - and all checked checkboxes will be available in `$_POST['test']`/`$_GET['test']`

Comment: @CodeBrauer my script was basically just to check if the article is checked.
function check() { 
if(document.getElementById("test").checked = true)
var x = true;
}
else{
var x = false;
}
I didn't know what to do next because I'm still new to PHP. I'll try what you just told me to do thanks.

Comment: Is your next step in another _php_ file or in the same file?

Comment: Just tried what CodeBrauer said, for each new article the checkbox has a unique ID.
@EhsanT my next step must me on another php file that regroups only the articles selected.

Comment: So you just need to wrap your loop in a `<form>` element and set the `action` of the `<form>` to your new php file. change the name of the _checkboxs_ to `name="test[]"` and gie the _article ID_ or any unique ID that you have for each article to their `value`. when you post your form, only the selected checkboxes will be posted and then you can access them in php like an array like this `$_POST['test'][0]`

Comment: Will do once I get home. I had all the answers I needed thanks.